# Disable power button on 2015 MBP

Tags: keyboard, power, keybindings

Me and my friends like having a laugh together and as part of that we turn each other computers off and spam tabs till the computer crashes. Is thee a way how to disable the power button on my MBP 2015 to prevent my friends from turning my computer by holding down the power button? If possible I would like to remap it to <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd>.

So far the only way to stop them is physically moving their hand away in time (which I always do). Would be nice to do my work without having to move their hand all the time!

Comment: You could pull the key off the keyboard so they have a much smaller target.

Comment: Would that void my warranty or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. While an individual press of the power button can be reconfigured into a keyboard shortcut/function using third party software, the Press and Hold feature of it is a failsafe commonly included with computer systems and is stored at the firmware level of the system to allow you to shut the system down should it lock up. You will not be able to change the behavior.